# Why are IE developer tools so slow?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

I've used the developer tools on Chrome, FF and IE, and on IE, it's extremely slow. I was trying to debug iGoogle and it took about 3 minutes to even open the tools page.

Can anyone confirm that it's that slow? It works fine on small websites though.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I have an Athlon 64 X2 6000, 4 GB RAM

Comment: I've found the same .. trying to debug the a MapGuide Fusion layout (2+ megs of script) is maddening.

Comment: It was not slow before. Only after starting with Windows 10, I noticed this problem. BTW: the current Edge is slow, too. Especially with complex pages, the DOM Explorer is ridiculously slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is that slow. I have noticed that FireBug has no issues running lengthly JS files where IE developer tools struggles.

Comment: Is there a way to use Developer Tools without struggling?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to clear the console a lot. (Right-click option in the console tab.) It does not clear the console ever except for when you manually do it, so it can get really big and slow. Usually clearing between every reload for me keeps it snappy enough.